# Why is this function that makes an array changing another variable?

Tags: c, arrays, function, variables

I have a function here

```
char ** makeArray(int count)
{
      char **array[count];
      return array[count];
}
```

that takes in the number of tokens from an array then returns an array with the correct size.
However for some reason it is changing count.

In my main function I use the function with this code:

```
char **dictionary;
dictionary = makeArray(count);
```

the value of count before using the function is 10, and after I use the function count's value becomes 6.

Comment: There must be more to your code than that.  Please create the smallest program possible that displays this bug and post it so that we may have more context.

Comment: Your function doesn't return an array - that's not possible. It returns a pointer to a local variable. That local variable is dead as soon as the function returns. Hence you have undefined behavior. You need to use `malloc` (or such) and remember to clean up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what c compiler you are using, but that code won't compile in VC++. If you want to declare an array at compile time, your "count" variable must be a compile time constant.

How about this?

```
char ** makeArray(int count)
{
    char** array = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*count);
    return array;
}
```

Remember to discard the array after using it or you will leak memory

```
free(array);
```

Comment: Your fix is correct (except that you shouldn't cast the return of malloc), but VC++'s failure to compile the code is because is doesn't support C99 which introduced VLAs (which the code in question (mis)uses).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes I have noticed that the Clang Objective C compiler allows specifying size of an array at runtime.